# How to sort a JOIN query between 2 tables with the corresponding SUM of a column in a 3rd table?

Tags: mysql, sorting, join, sum

I have the following simple query which works and does what I want:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.*, 
    Table2.*                    
FROM 
    Table1, Table2                          
WHERE 
    Table1.Col1 != '1' AND
    Table2.Col2 LIKE 'Miami' AND
    (Table2.Col3 LIKE 'USA' OR  Table2.Col2 LIKE 'US') AND  
    Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
```

I now need to sort those results by the SUM of the corresponding values in Table3 (`SUM(Table3.Col2)`) such that `Table3.Col1 = Table1.Col1` and `Table3.Col1 = Table2.Col1`.

I thought that simply adding those two lines in the WHERE clause plus `SUM(Table3.Col2)`  in the SELECT clause would do the trick, but that did not work and only returned **one** result with the total sum of all the `Table3.Col2` values, and not just the ones corresponding the matching rows in the other 2 tables.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.*, 
    Table2.*                    
FROM 
    Table1 JOIN Table2 on Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
    JOIN (SELECT Col1, SUM(Table3.Col2) as `SumCol` FROM Table3) as SumTable ON Table2.Col1 = SumTable.Col1                         
WHERE 
    Table1.Col1 != '1' AND
    Table2.Col2 LIKE 'Miami' AND
    (Table2.Col3 LIKE 'USA' OR  Table2.Col2 LIKE 'US') AND  
    Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
ORDER BY SumTable.SumCol DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.  Strangely, it produced almost the exact same single row result as my attempt, even though the queries look quite different.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some sample data from your tables, and perhaps a sample of what data result you are looking for.  You might want to add this to your question.